# Remove but not cancel local notification

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, uilocalnotification

`cancelAllLocalNotifications()` will as the name says, cancel all local notifications.

Consider that the phone has received a couple of notifications while the screen was in locked state. And we are only have interest in notifications received when the user actively are using the phone.

Is it possible to only clear these notifications from the list in the Notification Center, but without cancelling them?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use identifier for description your every notification, than you can only one notification removing, after this process you can setting notification again. I think this kind a trick working for your situation.

Comment: I thought of solving it in _applicationDidBecomeActive_ and there call cancelAllLocalNotifications(). Followed by a function call that schedules the notifications again. 
But as I understand it is not possible to only remove them from the list without cancel the scheduling?

Comment: Yes, as i know, that's it.